# SQL query to get the top "n" scores out of a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, puzzle

I'd like to find the different ways to solve a real life problem I had: imagine to have a contest, or a game, during which the users collect points. You have to build a query to show the list of users with the best "n" scores.

I'm making an example to clarify. Let's say that this is the Users table, with the points earned:

```
UserId - Points
1      - 100
2      -  75
3      -  50
4      -  50
5      -  50
6      -  25
```

If I want the top 3 scores, the result will be:

```
UserId - Points
1      - 100
2      -  75
3      -  50
4      -  50
5      -  50
```

This can be realized in a view or a stored procedure, as you want. My target db is Sql Server. Actually I solved this, but I think there are different way to obtain the result... faster or more efficent than mine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Untested, but should work:

```
select * from users where points in
(select distinct top 3 points from users order by points desc)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that works - I don't know if it's more efficient, and it's SQL Server 2005+

```
with scores as (
    select 1 userid, 100 points
    union select 2, 75
    union select 3, 50
    union select 4, 50
    union select 5, 50
    union select 6, 25
),
results as (
    select userid, points, RANK() over (order by points desc) as ranking 
    from scores
)
select userid, points, ranking
from results
where ranking <= 3
```

Obviously the first "with" is to set up the values, so you can test the second with, and final select work - you could start at "with results as..." if you were querying against an existing table.

Comment: I have a similar issue and was trying to use MAX and then I read your answer and remembered DENSE_RANK.  Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select top 3 with ties points 
from scores
order by points desc
```

Not sure if "with ties" works on anything other the SQL Server.

On SQL Server 2005 and up, you can pass the "top" number as an int parameter:

```
select top (@n) with ties points 
from scores
order by points desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually a modification to the WHERE IN, utilizing an INNER JOIN will be much faster.

```
SELECT 
   userid, points 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT TOP N 
      points 
   FROM users 
   ORDER BY points DESC
) AS p ON p.points = u.points
```

Answer (score 0):

@bosnic, I don't think that will work as requested, I'm not that familiar with MS SQL but I would expect it to return only 3 rows, and ignore the fact that 3 users are tied for 3rd place.

Something like this should work:

```
select userid, points 
   from scores 
   where points in (select top 3 points 
                       from scores 
                       order by points desc) 
   order by points desc
```

Answer (score 0):

@Espo thanks for the reality check - added the sub-select to correct for that.

I think the easiest response is to:

```
select userid, points from users
where points in (select distinct top N points from users order by points desc)
```

If you want to put that in a stored proc which takes N as a parameter, then you'll either have to do read the SQL into a variable then execute it, or do the row count trick:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(2000)
set @SQL = "select userID, points from users "
set @SQL = @SQL + " where points in (select distinct top " + @N
set @SQL = @SQL + " points from users order by points desc)"

execute @SQL
```

<strike>or</strike>

```
SELECT  UserID, Points
FROM     (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC)
         AS Row, UserID, Points FROM Users)
        AS usersWithPoints
WHERE  Row between 0 and @N
```

Both examples assume SQL Server and haven't been tested.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob#37760:

```
select top N points from users order by points desc
```

This query will only select 3 rows if N is 3, see the question. "Top 3" should return 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Hamilton

Your answer works with the example above but would not work if the data set was 100, 75, 75, 50, 50 (where it would return only 3 rows). TOP WITH TIES only includes the ties of the last row returned...

Answer (score 0):

Crucible got it (assuming SQL 2005 is an option).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select top N points from users order by points desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found all the other answers bit long and inefficient 
My answer would be:

`select * from users order by points desc limit 0,5`

this will render top 5 points